# How to add App logo on DMG EULA screen

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, installation, dmg

I am using following steps provided in old apple document(May 6, 2003) to display software license agreement (SLA) before mounting a disk image.[[1]](https://www.tribler.org/MacDiskimage/)

Download [slas_for_udifs_1.0.dmg](http://kayapo.tribler.org/trac/raw-attachment/wiki/MacDiskimage/SLAs_for_UDIFs_1.0.dmg) for SLAResources file.
STEP BY STEP

> 1. Create a disk image and populate it with files.
> 2. Use 'hdiutil convert' on the command line to convert the image file to type UDRO (UDIF read-only) or type UDCO (UDIF
>      read-only/compressed).  Beware of 'hdiutil convert' adding ".dmg" to
>      your filename.  ie. 'hdiutil convert -format UDCO image.dmg -o
>      image.ro'
> 3. 'hdiutil unflatten' the image file to expose its resources (you can add resources to a flat UDIF, but they won't have any affect).  ie.
>      'hdiutil unflatten image.ro.dmg'
> 4. Add the LPic, STR#, TEXT, and styl resources to the image file.  The  commands: DeRez SLAResources > sla.r Rez -a sla.r -o
>      myunflattenedimage.dmg will append the provided resources onto your
>      unflattened dimage.  You'll still want to customize the resources
>      (probably with ResEdit).
> 5. Open your image file with Disk Copy and test the SLA.
> 6. 'hdiutil flatten' your image for distribution.  ie. 'hdiutil flatten image.ro.dmg'

How to add app logo on EULA screen?

Comment: Apple does not have any documentation related to this. I think it is not possible.

Comment: Wondering, did you ever figure this out? My theory would be that the LPic resource could be related somehow. There is a lot of stuff which seems to work in this area which Apple haven't documented (e.g. "RTF "), so it could be an undocumented fourcc also.

Comment: I rescued a perl script that does this ( https://github.com/obaqueiro/eulagise-dmg ) unfortunately it does not work in Catalina.

Comment: @obaqueiro Thanks. I'll check it.